# R: data management and row names

Tags: r, date

I have the following data:

```
transaction <- c(1,2,3);
date <- c("2010-01-31","2010-02-28","2010-03-31");
type <- c("debit", "debit", "credit");
amount <- c(-500, -1000.97, 12500.81);
oldbalance <- c(5000, 4500, 17000.81)
evolution <- data.frame(transaction, date, type, amount, oldbalance, row.names=transaction, stringsAsFactors=FALSE);
evolution <- transform(evolution, newbalance = oldbalance + amount);
evolution
```

I specify the `row.names= transaction` but the output gives:

```
  transaction       date   type   amount oldbalance newbalance
1           1 2010-01-31  debit  -500.00    5000.00    4500.00
2           2 2010-02-28  debit -1000.97    4500.00    3499.03
3           3 2010-03-31 credit 12500.81   17000.81   29501.62
```

The problem is the additional numbers `1 to 3` that precedes the `date` field. How to get rid of this?

Update: I would like the output to look like:

```
  transaction       date   type   amount oldbalance newbalance
            1 2010-01-31  debit  -500.00    5000.00    4500.00
            2 2010-02-28  debit -1000.97    4500.00    3499.03
            3 2010-03-31 credit 12500.81   17000.81   29501.62
```

that is with the `transaction` column containing its values.

Thanks.

Comment: Does not compute. transaction is a column, you can remove it with `evolution[, -1]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following up on @Michelle's answer: data frames in R must have row names.  However, if you want to print the data frame without the row names you could:

```
print(evolution,row.names=FALSE)
```

(See `?print.data.frame`)

It's probably inadvisable, but you could hack the definition of `print.data.frame` as follows to mask the built-in function:

```
print.data.frame <- function(x,...) { 
   base:::print.data.frame(x,row.names=FALSE,...)
}
```

Comment: and what is most confusing is the updated output the OP gave, which still has the row names but has essentially deleted the transaction data, while still leaving the variable in the data frame. If transaction == row.name, using your method will allow the OP to know the pointer to the row if they ever want to operate at that level, because row.name is still accessible.

Answer (score 2):

you can't get rid of them, as they are a feature of R, see
`?row.names`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to omit transaction column in resulted data.frame?

```
evolution <- data.frame(date, type, amount, oldbalance, row.names=transaction, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Did it help?

Comment: @ DrDom Thanks but then the Transaction heading does not appear. I would like to remove the second set of 1 to 3 that appears just before the date column. The Transaction column should still be here.